# Brownian motion book or course

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I want to start studying Brownian motion, any book or course you recommend? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hida, Takeyuki. "Brownian motion."  Springer, New York, NY, 1980.
https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-6030-1

Karatzas, Ioannis, and Steven Shreve. Brownian motion and stochastic calculus. Vol. 113. Springer Science & Business Media, 2012.

Mörters, Peter, and Yuval Peres. Brownian motion. Vol. 30. Cambridge University Press, 2010.   Available at
https://people.bath.ac.uk/maspm/book.pdf

Le Gall, Jean-François. Brownian motion, martingales, and stochastic calculus. Vol. 274. Berlin: Springer, 2016.

For all these books, you can find reviews on the web that can help you determine the best fit to your interests.